# Lines outside the point grid

Tags: ios, swift, grid, lines

I have "bug" in setting lines between points in grid . If I click outside the grid I can make line going "nowhere" . I must set line only between 2 points in the grid ( horizontal and vertical) . I try to find where is the issue ,but can't figure out where exactly is the problem ,  to fix it

[image]

```
  func setup() {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showMoreActions(touch:)))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}


//draw line
func addLine(start: CGPoint,end:CGPoint) {

    let line = CAShapeLayer()
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()

    linePath.move(to: start)
    linePath.addLine(to: end)
    line.path = linePath.cgPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    line.lineWidth = 2
    line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    layer.addSublayer(line)

}



//  draw line between points
func showMoreActions(touch: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self)

    let (start, end) = findEndPoints(touchPt: touchPoint)
    addLine(start: start, end: end)

}

func findEndPoints(touchPt: CGPoint) -> (pt1: CGPoint, pt2: CGPoint) {

    //calculate where the touch is done

    let viewWidth =  self.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = self.bounds.height

    let gridRowWidth: CGFloat = viewWidth - diameter/4
    let gridColumnHeight: CGFloat = viewHeight - diameter/4

    let cellWidth: CGFloat = gridRowWidth / CGFloat(pointsOnRow)
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = gridColumnHeight / CGFloat(pointsOnColumn)

    // convert touch point to grid coordinates
    let gridX = ( CGFloat(touchPt.x) /  CGFloat(cellWidth) ) - 0.5
    let gridY = ( CGFloat(touchPt.y) / CGFloat(cellHeight) ) - 0.5

    // snap to nearest point in the grid
    let snapX = round(gridX)
    let snapY = round(gridY)

    // find distance from touch to snap point

    let distX = abs(gridX - snapX)
    let distY = abs(gridY - snapY)


    // start second point on top of first
    var secondX = snapX
    var secondY = snapY


    if distX < distY {
        // this is a vertical line
        if secondY > gridY {
            secondY -= 1
        } else {
            secondY += 1
        }
    } else {
        //this is a horizontal line
        if secondX > gridX {
            secondX -= 1
        } else {
            secondX += 1
        }
    }

    let halfdot = CGFloat(diameter) / 2

    // convert line points to view coordinates
    let pt1 = CGPoint(x: (snapX + 0.5) * CGFloat(cellWidth) + halfdot, y: (snapY + 0.5) * CGFloat(cellHeight) + halfdot)

    let pt2 = CGPoint(x: (secondX + 0.5) * CGFloat(cellWidth) + halfdot, y: (secondY + 0.5) * CGFloat(cellHeight) + halfdot)

    return (pt1, pt2)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Or using test cases to find where things break?

Comment: @KSigWyatt I am new in Swift and yes I try to debug it , but I can find where exactly is the issue , and no for first time I heard that there is test cases in Xcode

Comment: I would recommend then adding print statements between each line in the code to see what lines are working. Or you can run in debug mode and it may tell you on which line the application is breaking. It could also be that the code allows for lines to be drawn in unknown directions. Perhaps adding some kind of conditional statement to prevent this behavior is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the grid function was re-worked :

```
let squareSide = self.bounds.width
    let distanceBetweenPointsOnRow = ( squareSide - 2 * pointStartPosition ) / (pointsOnRow - 1)
    let distanceBetweenPointsOnColumn = ( squareSide - 2 * pointStartPosition ) / (pointsOnColumn - 1)

    for n in 0..<self.pointsOnRow {
        for m in 0..<self.pointsOnColumn {

            let circleX: CGFloat = pointStartPosition + (CGFloat(n) * distanceBetweenPointsOnRow - diameter/2)
            let circleY: CGFloat = pointStartPosition + (CGFloat(m) * distanceBetweenPointsOnColumn - diameter/2)
```

and the function that calc where to be put the line now is :

```
  let squareSide = self.bounds.width

    let distanceBetweenPoints = ( squareSide - 2 * pointStartPosition ) / (CGFloat(pointsOnColumn) - 1)

    // convert touch point to grid coordinates
    let gridX = (touchPt.x - pointStartPosition)/distanceBetweenPoints
    let gridY = (touchPt.y - pointStartPosition)/distanceBetweenPoints
```

with check :

```
    // check if the user is clicked outside the point grid
    if secondX < 0 || secondY < 0 || secondY > (CGFloat(pointsOnColumn) - 1) || secondX > (CGFloat(pointsOnRow) - 1) || snapX < 0 || snapY < 0 || snapY > (CGFloat(pointsOnColumn) - 1) || snapX > (CGFloat(pointsOnRow) - 1) {
        return nil
    }
```